# How to make a generic class and function so if I pass an object that will return a JSON in Swift/Obj-C?

Tags: json, objective-c, swift, generics

```swift
class Type1 {
    var member1: String?
    var member2: String?
    init(member1: String,member2: String) {
        self.member1 = member1
        self.member2 = member2
    }
}

class Type2 {
    var member3: String?
    var member4: String?
    init(member3: String,member4: String) {
        self.member3 = member3
        self.member4 = member4
    }
}
```

Looking for some class with function that I can pass objects of Type1 or Type2 will return JSON data. Please note that I am looking for a solution based on generics.

For Type1 will return -

```
{
    "member1" : "someValue1",
    "member2" : "someValue2"
}
```

For Type2 will return -

```
{
    "member3" : "someValue3",
    "member4" : "someValue4"
}
```

Comment: You don't need generics. All you have to do is to make your types conform to `Codable` protocol, use `JSONEncoder` to get a dictionary and use `JSONSerialization` to get a JSON string

Comment: BTW, the return values you provided are not in JSON format. JSON requires key-value pairs to be comma-separated.

Comment: Ya, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define a protocol, e.g., `JsonRepresentable`

```
protocol JsonRepresentable: Encodable {
    func asJson() -> String?
}
```

Let's also provide the default implementation of the method `asJson()`

```
extension JsonRepresentable {
    func asJson() -> String? {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(self)
        
        if let jsonData = jsonData {
            let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            
            return json
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is it, actually. The only thing we need now, is to conform our types to this protocol

```
class Type1: JsonRepresentable {...
class Type2: JsonRepresentable {...
```

And use what we did:

```
print(Type1(member1: "member1", member2: "member2").asJson()!)
// prints {"member1":"member1","member2":"member2"}

print(Type2(member3: "member3", member4: "member4").asJson()!)
// prints {"member3":"member3","member4":"member4"}
```